# Separate string from numeric in single Pandas Dataframe column and create two new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, extract

I'm shocked that no one has asked this on SO before.. since it seems like a simple enough of a problem.

I have a single column in a pandas Dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['APPLEGATE WINERY    455.292049'],['AMAND FARM  849.827192'],['COBB FARM ST    1039.49357'],['DIRIGIA 2048.947284']], columns = ['Col1'])

    Col1
0   APPLEGATE WINERY 455.292049
1   AMAND FARM 849.827192
2   COBB FARM ST 1039.49357
3   DIRIGIA 2048.947284
```

And I just want to separate the string characters from the numeric, so the result should look like this

```
Name                Area
APPLEGATE WINERY    455.292049
AMAND FARM          849.827192
COBB FARM ST        1039.49357
DIRIGIA             2048.947284
```

I know I can use [Regular Expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) in python, but this seems like overkill since a) it's just a separation of data types and b) the strings have different lengths and the numerics have different numbers of digits.

So one result would start to look like this:

```
df['Name'] = df.Col1.str.extract('([A-Z]\w{0,})', expand=True)
df['Area'] = df.Col1.str.extract('(\d)', expand=True)
```

But is there a nice, clean solution out there to solve this problem without going through the hassle of using RegEx and instead separating strings from numerics into two columns?

Comment: Could you possibly have a `32nd Street`?

Comment: No all of the names start with an alphabet letter not numeric.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a single `extract` call. You'll also want to strip trailing whitespaces from the result if you use this regex.

```
df2 = (df['Col1'].str.extract(r'(?P<Name>.*?)(?P<Area>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)')
                 .applymap(str.strip))
df2
               Name         Area
0  APPLEGATE WINERY   455.292049
1        AMAND FARM   849.827192
2      COBB FARM ST   1039.49357
3           DIRIGIA  2048.947284
```

**Regex Breakdown**

```
(?P<Name>   # first named capture group - "Name"
    .*?     # match anything (non-greedy)
)
(?P<Area>   # second named group - "Area"
    \d+     # match one or more digits,
    (?:     
       \.   # decimal
       \d+  # trailing digits
    )?      # the `?` indicates floating point is optional
)
```

PS, to convert the "Area" column to numeric, use `pd.to_numeric`.

Comment: I really appreciate the explanation of the RegEx! Thanks much. To get this solution to work I also had to convert the Dataframe to string `.astype(str)` because I previously got the error `Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas` but now it works.

Comment: @JAG2024 You're welcome. The idea behind the regex is to find what looks like a floating point number and capture that as the second group "Area", then capture everything before it as "Name". Glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Feel like you can just do `str.rsplit`

```
df.Col1.str.rsplit(' ',1,expand=True).apply(lambda x : x.str.strip(),1)
Out[314]: 
                  0            1
0  APPLEGATE WINERY   455.292049
1        AMAND FARM   849.827192
2      COBB FARM ST   1039.49357
3           DIRIGIA  2048.947284
```

Comment: This is a good solution assuming there are not trailing spaces in the column. Try `df.Col1.str.strip().str.rsplit(...)` Nice one!

Answer (score 1):

You can use rsplit. It will split the string starting from the right.

```
pd.DataFrame(df.Col1.str.rsplit(' ',1).tolist(), columns = ['Name','Area'])

Result:
    Name                Area
0   APPLEGATE WINERY    455.292049
1   AMAND FARM          849.827192
2   COBB FARM ST       1039.49357
3   DIRIGIA            2048.947284
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
df.Col1.str.extract('(.*\S)\s+([\d\.]+)')
```

Output:

```
                  0            1
0  APPLEGATE WINERY   455.292049
1        AMAND FARM   849.827192
2      COBB FARM ST   1039.49357
3           DIRIGIA  2048.947284
```

Comment: Realized that and just fixed.